# Trying to find the font used in this logo

Tags: font-identification

We can't get the information from our designer, so we are trying to find out what fonts were used in these different logos.  I have tried using 5 different font identifiers and can't seem to get to a "close match".

[image: Collège Servite]

Comment: To see the other logo please click on the link "Doctus Pro Maria Depuis 1233"

Comment: So far I have been able to identify "Baker Signet" for COLLEGE SERVITE

Comment: Please stick to one ID request per question

Comment: Oh! ok ! Will post other ones.  Didn't want to overload the forum ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary font displaying "COLLEGE SERVITE" in this logo is [Baker Signet](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tilde/baker-signet/regular/):

[image]

[WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) seemed to have no issues identifying it.

Comment: Thanks after trying 10 different apps, I was able to finally find it too.

Comment: To your opinion, do you think it would show that much if I use Baker Signet for the other one "FONDATION COLLEGE SERVITE" ?

Comment: My main concern is about the "DOCTUS PRO MARIA DEPUIS 1233:"  This one is really not easy.....even with 10 different apps and website....;)

Comment: @Annie-ClaudePeniguel I've definitely seen it before, but I can't recall what it is. It's quite old (so am I). I think that Letraset may have done it.

Comment: Thanks Mick, I have the same feeling...I am older too....seen it before, but can't find it...it's frustrating...hahaha !  We used to use this calligraphic style in my Latin classes back in the 70'.