# Trying to find the "rare" font used in this logo

Tags: fonts, logo

I was asked to post one question per logo....so here we are :

We can't get the information from our designer, so we are trying to find out what fonts were used in these different logos. I have tried using 10 different font identifiers and can't seem to get to a "close match".
For the purpose, I have removed the "emblem" part of the logo.

Thanks in advance for your help !

[image: DOCTUS PRO MARIA DEPUIS 1233]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to find the font used in these different logos](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87268/trying-to-find-the-font-used-in-these-different-logos)

Comment: @Scott It's part of our [font ID requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366/23061) to ask about one font per question. Hence why she asked this question

Comment: This is definitely an Uncial font. The closest that I have got so far is [Boyd Uncial](http://www.fontspace.com/william-boyd/boyduncial), but the letters A and M do not match.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if the letter M is from another font, since its serifs and terminals are different. If so, this may also be true for the letter A.

Comment: Thanks Mick....desperately trying to get hold of the graphist ;)

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I have found my answer !  There is 3 fonts used in this logo 1) Mearschaum 2) Scotford for the "M" 3) A= Thorfont for the "A"....Now I have to tweak everything in Photoshop for it to look the same and be reusable in all our publications ;)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all your help. I have found my answer ! There is 3 fonts used in this logo 1) Mearschaum 2) Scotford for the "M" 3) A= Thor font for the "A"....Now I have to tweak everything in Photoshop for it to look the same and be reusable in all our publications ;)

[Mearschaum Font](https://ufonts.com/search/Mearschaum)

[Thor Font](https://ufonts.com/fonts/thor.html)

[Scotford Uncial Font](https://ufonts.com/fonts/scotford-uncial-normal.html)